# Django static files are saved recursively creating bloat via collectstatic

Tags: django, nginx

When running collectstatic on my production system, it seems like a bunch of files is stored recursively e.g. (real example):

```
'production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/production/css/lib/nestable/nestable.css'
```

This causes bloat every time I update my static files (which is necessary when I update any javascript for the front-end).

My settings.py file has the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/production/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = ([
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

])
```

I also have `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in my main urls.py

In my Nginx available-sites config file I have the following lines:

```
location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/myapp/static/production/;
        expires modified +1w;
    }
```

To circumvent this issue, I now have to run collectstatic -c and delete all my static files with every update which isn't ideal.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused, because you're storing your collected static files inside your static sources directory.

Static files in Django can come from any Django application, as applications can define their own static files. To simplify your server configuration, all static files has to be collected from your project and from all used applications to one directory from which your web server can serve them.

`STATIC_ROOT` is the location of this central directory into which all static files will be collected.

`STATIC_URL` is reflecting your `STATIC_ROOT` from the web server endpoint. In other words, on this URL all files from `STATIC_URL` will be served by your server.

`STATICFILES_DIRS` together with `static` directories from each application are the directories from which all files should be collected (copied over) to the `STATIC_ROOT` directory.

In your example, you are storing your `STATIC_ROOT` inside a path defined in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, so after each run of the `collectstatic` django will copy over everything from `STATICFILES_DIRS` into your `STATIC_ROOT`, including the contents of the `STATIC_ROOT` it copied over previously.

To fix your issue, isolate those 2 locations in your file system and adjust your Django settings accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so to make sure I get this right: all my static files are already stored in a single location, and none from the individual apps. Is it then that STATICFILES_DIRS is superfluous?

Comment: Yes, but... If you've collected the staticfiles from all your apps (including 3rd party ones and for example django admin) and you are storing all of that in your repository, you should stop doing that and rely on the staticfiles collection. The staticfiles collection can also be helpful in some additional static serving solution (like amazon S3).

Comment: Thanks, I don't use collectstatic on my dev machine, only in production, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you could try

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'production')
```